# Run script every hour in Mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, cron

I am struggling the last 3 hours to make a script run every hour in Mac OS X 10.11.5. Here is what I have, scheduled to run every minute for testing purposes (which doesn't seem to be executed):

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:position_scheduler gsamaras$ cat position.sh
#!/bin/bash

current_hour="`date +%H`";
echo $current_hour;
osascript -e 'display notification "Hour '$current_hour'" with title "Title"'

filename=state.txt
oldState="`cat /Users/gsamaras/Documents/position_scheduler/state.txt`"
newState=$((1-oldState))

if [ -f "$filename" ]
then 
    echo "$newState" > "$filename"
    echo $newState
fi
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:position_scheduler gsamaras$ cd
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ crontab * * * * * root /Users/gsamaras/Documents/position_scheduler/position.sh
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ crontab -l
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ crontab * * * * * /Users/gsamaras/Documents/position_scheduler/position.sh
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ crontab -l
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$
```

What am I missing?

---

I tried also with:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ export EDITOR=nano
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.clUrdAyyv9":0: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install
Do you want to retry the same edit? n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.clUrdAyyv9
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ cat /tmp/crontab.clUrdAyyv9 
crontab * * * * * /Users/gsamaras/Documents/position_scheduler/position.sh
```

Comment: If you want to make an entry in crontab, you should first set your preferred editor (`export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi` or `nano` or similar) then run `crontab -e` and add your job.

Comment: Uhhm, I am getting an error with that approach @MarkSetchell `"/tmp/crontab.bZ1bHmQMHQ":0: bad minute
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install`. I hope I did exactly what you had in mind though...

Comment: Still an error @MarkSetchell, check my edit.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, 5 stars. Use `crontab -e` to edit and `crontab -l` to list/view after editing.

Comment: Same error @MarkSetchell :/

Comment: @gsamaras The word "crontab" doesn't belong at the beginning of the line. Also, that cronjob specification would run every _minute_, not every hour.

Comment: @duskwuff that's it! Thanks! I did that for testing..Go ahead and post an answer please, thank you very much! :D